# if statement not working, seems to be a type error

Tags: python, types, serial-port

I'm running this code at the moment, it's imbedded in some other stuff which is why it has `self.` before the variables. The `ser.readline()` will return 1. But I think it's a `string`, `'1'`. Anyway the upshot of it is my `if` statement isn't working and I think it's because of some type mismatch, but I can't put my finger on it. I've tried everything to make it work. As `print self._dinput_value` returns 1 and its type is `str`, I'm stumped.

Anyway here it is:

```
 print "sending data"
 ser.write("6" + "," +str(self._pin_no) +","+"1")
 time.sleep(1)
 self._dinput_value = ser.readline(2)
 print self._dinput_value
 print type(self._dinput_value)
 time.sleep(1)

if str(self._dinput_value) =="1":
    self._d = False
    return self._d
elif str(self._dinput_value) == "2":
    self._d =True
    return self._d

else:
    print "CODE EXITED with ERROR ??: Arduino went funny, sorry"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use print. Use repr to see what the value is. I think there may be a newline after the 1.

Comment: Posting the specific error and traceback makes us not have to guess as much when trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

`readline()` does not remove trailing newline characters.  The value is likely `"1\n"` (the `\n` sequence being a newline) which is why the equality test fails.

Try adding an `rstrip()` method call, like so:

```
self._dinput_value = ser.readline(2).rstrip()
```

This will remove all trailing whitespace from the string.

---

If you are having trouble debugging something like this, try `print(repr(x))` where `x` is the value you are having problems with.  It will display the Python representation of the value.  If it's a string, for example, special characters like newlines will be converted to escape sequences so that you can see exactly what the value contains:

```
>>> x = sys.stdin.readline()
1
>>> print(repr(x))
'1\n'
```